# Magento 2: Command returned non-zero exit code during submission on marketplace

Tags: magento2, marketplace, setup-di-compile, production-mode, submission

I have submitted a module to the marketplace, I have tested it by all cases. I have switched to production mode but I am not getting any errors. However, I am getting a failure on submission with the below errors.

> Enabling maintenance mode Starting compilation Something went wrong
>   while compiling generated code. See the error log for details.
>   Disabling maintenance mode Command returned non-zero exit code:
>   `/usr/bin/php -f /var/www/html/bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Environment: PHP 7.1.22 Magento 2.3 CE
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the below steps to fix this kind of issue.

1) Remove var/* generation/* and try to run that command again. And provide proper permission for var/ generation and pub folder.

2) Check logs and see if you find any issue, please fix it and try again.

3) Try to update the PHP.INI values.

```
php.ini values are:

post_max_size = 1024M 
upload_max_filesize = 1024M 
memory_limit = 3G 
max_execution_time = 500
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thank you, but I am not getting errors, MarkePlace review gets an error.

Answer (score 1):

**Change the mode and skip the compilation:**

```
php magento deploy:mode:set production --skip-compilation

php magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB
```

Magento default locale is en_US so you have to define your language.

If that fails, make sure your /var and pub/ have the correct permissions

It could be that your PHP is exhausted so increasing the limit in php.ini should help but skipping the compilation and compiling after switch is a good workaround.

Also, make sure your store in use has a valid theme selected, it might be that you are using a theme that doesn't exist in the system.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the extension prevents product and category pages from being cached by Varnish. One possible cause is using **cacheable="false"** in one or more blocks on product and category pages.

Additional resources: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish.html